# The "spooky action at a distance" and reference frame

Tags: quantum-entanglement, lorentz-symmetry, epr-experiment

It is often said that the measurement in EPR experiment is instant, as somehow described as "spooky action at a distance". However, the notation of equal time depends on reference frame, according to Lorentz transformation.

I found this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0007009 "Experimental test of non-local quantum correlation in relativistic configurations". It is claimed

> One detector is set in motion so that both detectors, each in
>   its own inertial reference frame, are first to do the measurement

Does this experiment violate Lorentz transformation? Why or why not?

Comment: "Instant" is not a useful concept in relativity. At most two distant measurements can be synchronized in a resting, i.e. special reference frame. In all other frames they will not be happening at the same time in the moving frame, so the concept of "instant" is really observer dependent (and thus unphysical). Similarly it's a bad habit to talk about "spooky action at a distance". An action is a well defined quantity in physics (even in relativity) and the correlation seen in EPR experiments does not represent the existence of a physical action. Lorentz symmetry is not violated by EPR.

Comment: Nonetheless we can still analyze the correlation of the outcomes by the two experimentalists in the EPR experiment in a given reference frame.E.g. one got +, the other got -. Then we infer if the "wavefunction collapse" happens instant or not.If does not, one experimentalist got +, the other can get + as well in a shorter period of time (assume they have establish classical channel).If it is instant, one experimentalist got +, the other should get - despite how short time interval.I think this point it critical in analyzing the correlations, and hardly be trivialized by Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Correlations are not the same as an action. There is no physical reality to a wave function collapse. "Collapse of the wavefunction" is a different way of saying that the Born rule is being applied. Now, if I understand this correctly, the Born rule is not violated in this experiment, either. The "instancy" of the Born rule sounds like a misinterpretation of the constancy of the result of a measurement AFTER the fact. How long it actually took the physical process inside the measurement apparatus to produce that result has usually nothing in common with that interpretation.

Comment: Let me avoid the word "action", since it is put in the quotation in the question anyway. Whether wavefunction collapse has a physical reality would require a definition of physical reality, let me avoid this question for a moment as well. I think how long the measurement take/or the Born's rule applies is a testable problem. If it is instant, one experimentalist got +, the other should get - despite how short time interval it is. If the measurement takes time, at 3:00 pm e.g., one got -, the other may also get - at 3:00 pm. And it is the core issue in this question.

Comment: So you are down to the question of whether the Born rule applies. Does it not, in this experiment? As has been pointed out in case of this particular paper, it seems to muddle a non-relativistic analysis with a (not even) relativistic experimental setup. There are a lot of unnecessary elements, the absolute separation plays no importance for relativity, neither does the attempt to make the setup equidistant. The detector is not actually in relativistic motion (c>>105m/s). Truthfully, I would give this paper a D- to begin with.

Comment: My central concern is, people say in EPR experiment, one person got +, the other instantly got - (by Born's rule , e.g.) "Instant" depends on reference frame. Does Born's rule admit a privilege reference frame? If not, in which frame it is instant?

Comment: The phrase "instant" is meaningless, both for matters of relativity as well as quantum mechanics. You are basically asking a non-physical question and the experiment you cite is, in my opinion, very poorly designed to answer a meaningful one.

Comment: Why "instant" is meaningless in the matter of quantum mechanics? and What do you mean by "There is no physical reality to a wave function collapse"

Comment: Because how long a measurement actually takes depends on the microscopic structure of the detector. That, of course, is completely independent of the question of what a sufficiently "fast" detector will detect in this particular non-relativistic setup (where is something "fast" moving in here???), which, again, seems completely unrelated to the precise relativistic form of the Born rule (or even the existence thereof).

Comment: @CuriousOne Apr 26 '15 at 21:47 : this experiment is generally considered as fundamental for the non locality theory

Comment: @igael: non-locality is not a theory but a philosophical belief about how the world ought to be when it is pretty obvious that the world is not like that.